# Spool Results from Cursor Into Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, salesforce, dbamp

I have a cursor that I'm using to find NULL columns in a database.  I'm using this to eliminate NULL Columns from an upload of this data to Salesforce using dbAMP. I'd like to modify this to spool the results into a Table and include the Table Name and Column name.

```
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = 
c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'Account'

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * FROM Account WHERE [' + @col + 
'] IS NOT NULL) BEGIN print ''' + @col + ''' end'
EXEC(@cmd)

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo
```

I've have not had any success in modifying this cursor to put results in a table.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Print a Select then Insert into (tbl with same column definition). 
Create a table with the same columns in the same order. 
Then put an Insert into yourtable(your columns in the same order as output from the exec(). 
Any change in table columns in the future may break this. The table and the query should have the same columns. If you are cautious and control the order of columns in the select and insert, it shouldn't matter about the table column order, but it is still good practice imho.

Example (insert into table with dynamic sql)

```
if object_id('dbo.ColumnMatch','U') is not null drop table dbo.ColumnMatch;
create table dbo.ColumnMatch (
     id int identity(1,1) not null primary key
    ,column_name varchar(512)
);

declare @col varchar(256) = 'This Column Name'
declare @s varchar(max) = 'select ''' + @col + '''';

insert into ColumnMatch (column_name)
exec(@s);

select * from ColumnMatch;
```

Not Print but select and fix the Insert Into statement. :)

```
if object_id('dbo.ColumnMatch','U') is not null drop table dbo.ColumnMatch;
create table dbo.ColumnMatch (
     id int identity(1,1) not null primary key
    ,column_name varchar(512)
);
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = 
c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'Account'

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * FROM Account WHERE [' + @col + 
'] IS NOT NULL) BEGIN select ''' + @col + ''' column_name end'
Insert into ColumnMatch (column_name)
EXEC(@cmd)

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo

select * from ColumnMatch;
```